# Can't connect with Office 365 when publish Website to Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: c#, azure, deployment, virtual, office365

I wrote a program in C# that connects to Office 365 and creates a user mailbox in an Azure virtual machine.

It's okay when I run my program in an Azure virtual machine (Windows server 2012) or in my Local Windows 7 computer. The user is created. I checked in EAC and Powershell.

But when I publish the website (deploy into Azure) into my Azure Subscription account, I could not create a user.

I think something's wrong in the connection string. However, as mentioned above, the user is created on the local computer and Azure virtual machine (Windows server 2012 virtual machine).

Do I need to have more settings for Azure to run my program correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You need config "Internet information (ISS) Manager"

In Virtual Machine Windows Server 2012. You Open "Management tool" --> Open "Internet information (ISS) Manager --> Select Your Windows server --> Select sub folder named: Application Pool --> Right click "DefaultAppPopl" --> Choose "Detail Setting" --> Set "Load user profile" vaule to "True"